# Delete wordpress posts with 0 views [wp_postviews plugin]

Tags: mysql, wordpress, post, view

This select works perfect in my opinion... any suggestion??

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_posts` ,  `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE  `post_type` =  'post'
AND post_id = ID
AND DATEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  `post_date` ) >400
AND meta_key =  "views"
AND meta_value =0;
```

the problem is that I don't know how I can I do a DELETE to remove all this posts! Any helps? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit, after comments - not tested, so possibly not 100% correct]

```
create table post_ids_to_remove (postid bigint);

insert into post_ids_to_remove (postid) values (
  SELECT post_id
      FROM  `wp_posts` ,  `wp_postmeta` 
      WHERE  `post_type` =  'post'
      AND post_id = ID
      AND DATEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  `post_date` ) >400
      AND meta_key =  "views"
      AND meta_value =0
)

delete from `wp_postmeta` where post_id in(
      SELECT postid
      FROM  `post_ids_to_remove`
);

delete from `wp_posts` where id in(
      SELECT postid
      FROM  `post_ids_to_remove`
);

drop table post_ids_to_remove;
```

Comment: I have a question!!! How can I execute the 2nd query if I deleted wp_postmeta in the first one?

Comment: And how can i create a temporary table?

Comment: Hi paul, I changed the queries. I create a table containing all the ids to be removed, and afterwards I drop the table again. Even better would be to create the table once, and empty the table at the end (by using the truncate table post_ids_to_remove; command)  every time instead of dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT into post_ids_to_remove (postid)

 SELECT ID FROM  wp_posts ,  wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'views' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 0;

 DELETE from `wp_postmeta` where post_id in(
          SELECT postid
          FROM  `post_ids_to_remove`
    );

 DELETE from `wp_posts` where id in(
          SELECT postid
          FROM  `post_ids_to_remove`
    );

 DROP table post_ids_to_remove;
```